# Using CodeBehind to change the LoginView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am wondering if there is a way to do this? I'm using windows authentication, and I have a list of groups the user belongs to. I then want to determine which loginview to use based on which group(s) they are part of. Because everyone accessing the site will be required to be logged in anyway the LoggedInTemplate and the AnonymousTemplate are not enough. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't quite follow. You can only know which group(s) a user belongs to after user has been authenticated. If user is already authenticated what is then the need for loggin in?

Comment: to clarify: you want to know the user BEFORE she logs in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using windows authentication

I'm just wondering why you would have the need for a LoginView control which would imply forms authentication. If you keep on using Windows authentication there's no need to have someone authenticating again via forms authentication. It makes no sense.

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks. I was having trouble visualizing what i was doing i guess. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

LoginView already supports multiple templates: one per defined role. See the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.rolegroups.aspx) on MSDN, especially the example.